# Why does my soldering iron not work after using it to melt plastic?

Tags: soldering

I don't understand what happened to my soldering iron. I just used it to melt a hole in a plastic box.  I unplugged the soldering iron for 1 or 2 minutes.  When I plugged it in again,  the light of the soldering iron was on but the iron didn't get hot :-( ...
I opened the soldering iron to see what happened but I didn't find any problem..
Where is the heating element...?

Comment: I apologise for my mistake.

Answer (score 8):

First, don't melt plastic with a soldering iron, at least if you want to use it for soldering afterwards.  That leaves residue on the tip which can make soldering difficult.

However, while melting plastic is a bad idea, it shouldn't make the iron not heat anymore.  The short answer, and really the only one we can give from your information, is that your solering iron broke.  Busted, crapped the bed, kaput.  If you are superstitious, then you should believe the soldering diety is punishing you for melting plastic with a soldering tool.  If there was one, he definitely should.

The failure could be in the base station, or it could be in the heating element in the iron.  Without actually diagnosing the problem and breaking it down, there is no way to tell.  If you or someone you know has the same model iron, you can swap base stations and see which component the failure follows.

Comment: helpful, dismissive, and scolding altogether, like a good parent. :)

Comment: Thank u sir for giving me a good direction for the use of soldering iron....and also for scolding me..
Becoz the way u scold me, it shows this is really very bad thing to melt plastic box using soldering iron.. 
Thanks sir

Comment: But sir they close my question.. 
Is this is right???

Answer (score 1):

Your question is impossible to answer because it's hard to tell what could have happened. But, if your soldering iron is rather inexpensive, then realize that they can and do break. For those cheap irons it's just easier to get a new one.

Comment: If u worked with such irons then u can tell me the reason.. 
This is not the solution to break it and check..
Bt yes i wil do that bt as a final soln..

Comment: The heating element might have broke. Those elements wear out. Melting plastic with them isn't always a good idea.

Comment: Bt after that i used another iron to melt and that iron is still good....